# How to porting Paging 3 from Kotlin Flow to Java? - Unable to find PagingDataFlow.create function

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-paging

Paging 3 just released few days ago.

Currently, we are porting the following Paging 3 example code, from Kotlin to Java.

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/a2151cf66483560f76b041ba95ce96e931c50caf/PagingSample/app/src/main/java/paging/android/example/com/pagingsample/CheeseViewModel.kt

### Kotlin

```
/**
 * We use the Kotlin API to construct a [Flow]<[PagingData]>. Java developers should use the
 * Java API: `PagingDataFlow.create`
 */
val allCheeses = Pager(
    PagingConfig(
        /**
         * A good page size is a value that fills at least a few screens worth of content on a
         * large device so the User is unlikely to see a null item.
         * You can play with this constant to observe the paging behavior.
         *
         * It's possible to vary this with list device size, but often unnecessary, unless a
         * user scrolling on a large device is expected to scroll through items more quickly
         * than a small device, such as when the large device uses a grid layout of items.
         */
        pageSize = 60,

        /**
         * If placeholders are enabled, PagedList will report the full size but some items might
         * be null in onBind method (PagedListAdapter triggers a rebind when data is loaded).
         *
         * If placeholders are disabled, onBind will never receive null but as more pages are
         * loaded, the scrollbars will jitter as new pages are loaded. You should probably
         * disable scrollbars if you disable placeholders.
         */
        enablePlaceholders = true,

        /**
         * Maximum number of items a PagedList should hold in memory at once.
         *
         * This number triggers the PagedList to start dropping distant pages as more are loaded.
         */
        maxSize = 200
    )
) {
    dao.allCheesesByName()
}.flow
```

---

### Java

Constructing a `PagingConfig` isn't much issue.

```
final int pageSize = 60;
final int prefetchDistance = pageSize;
final boolean enablePlaceholders = false;
final int initialLoadSize = pageSize * PagingConfig.DEFAULT_INITIAL_PAGE_MULTIPLIER;
final int maxSize = PagingConfig.MAX_SIZE_UNBOUNDED;
final int jumpThreshold = PagingSource.LoadResult.Page.COUNT_UNDEFINED;

PagingConfig pagingConfig = new PagingConfig(
        pageSize,
        prefetchDistance,
        enablePlaceholders,
        initialLoadSize,
        maxSize,
        jumpThreshold
);
```

But, we are stuck then.

The following code comment draws our attention.

> Java developers should use the Java API: `PagingDataFlow.create`

According to code comment, Java developer should use `PagingDataFlow.create`. But, from IDE, we really can't find a class named `androidx.paging.PagingDataFlow`.

We are expecting to have `LiveData` which we can observe. Kotlin's flow/ co-routine isn't something we are expecting in Java land.

Any idea how we can use `PagingDataFlow.create`?

Answer (score 3):

This documentation is unfortunately out of date as I had written this sample on top of an old snapshot and had forgotten to update it before release.

The API you're looking for is an extension property ontop of Pager. In Java, you should look for PagingLiveData.getLiveData(Pager)

See here for some more samples: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data#guava-livedata